# imap_fetchheader bytes vs actual file size

Tags: php, email, filesystems, imap

I'm using **imap_fetcheader** to get the attachments of a mail, just the content. Here's the code -

```
if (isset($content->ifdparameters) && $content->ifdparameters == 1 && isset($content->dparameters) && is_array($content->dparameters)) {
            foreach ($content->dparameters as $object) {
                if (isset($object->attribute) && preg_match('~filename~i', $object->attribute)) {                    
                    $attachment = new EmailAttachment();

                    $attachment->attachment_name = $object->value;                                                              
                    $attachment->attachment_size = $this->format_bytes($content->bytes);
                    $attachment->attachment_part_id = empty($actualpart) ? 1 : $actualpart;
                    $attachment->attachment_encoding = $content->encoding;
                    $results[] = $attachment;
                }
            }
        }
```

The `format_bytes` function is here -

```
private function format_bytes($bytes, $precision = 2) {
    $units = array('B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB');

    $bytes = max($bytes, 0);
    $pow = floor(($bytes ? log($bytes) : 0) / log(1024));
    $pow = min($pow, count($units) - 1);

    $bytes /= pow(1024, $pow);

    return round($bytes, $precision) . ' ' . $units[$pow];
}
```

When the user clicks on the attachment, I grab the attachment content from the mail server and echo the contents back.

The problem is that -

The bytes reported by the `$content->bytes` property is substantially different then what gets downloaded to the clients computer...

Is this a known issue?

The mail server is POSTFIX hosted on CentOS operating system.

Answer (score 2):

It's often about 33% bigger, because that's how much extra bulk base64 encoding adds.

It's not always 33%, though: There are other encodings, base64 is just the most common one for attachments.

Comment: So when I show the size to the user without actually downloading the attachment can I reduce it by 33% and show it to the user or would that be too bad an asumption?

Comment: It's reasonable most of the time, but that size actually reflects the data usage.  There are cases where it may be quoted-printable encoded instead, or maybe not encoded at all (plain ascii.txt document).  You would need to find out the encoding before adjusting it.  If it's base64, that's a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Also, that's PHP math ;) You would need to reduce it by 25%, not 33%. Add 33% to 3 and you have 4. Now reduce by 25% and you have 3 again.